# Intellisense doesn't work for MVVM light toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-toolkit

I began to use MVVM pattern yesterday.But for working with events i needed to install MVVM light toolkit.I did that,and added library to references.At UserControl i announced that library,but  when i want to use toolkit whatever i write it doesnt show any suggestions and doesnt accept what i want to write and shows this error "A value of type 'EventToCommand' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerActionCollection' "

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextChanged">
   <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Test}"/>
</EventTrigger>
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use it like this ..

Namespace to add :
`xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=UserControlLoadedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Dont forget to add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your project

You need To Use `PassEventArgsToCommand="True"` in

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=UserControlLoadedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And then you can get that at ViewModel ..... you Might Need to use `Generic RelayCommand` as

```
RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs> myCommand= new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(Execute,CanExecute)
```

Comment: now i tested it.but it is doesnt raise event(command) when it must rise.I couldnt understand what the problem

Comment: which dll you use?i use GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4

Comment: well,i could solve this,but there is another problem now.I bind preview key down event,because of that it must return keyEventArgs but it returns null

Comment: @JavidanGuliyev se Edited answer