# SelectedItem property of ListBox changes when SelectedIndex property changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Can I change the SelectedItem of ListBox by SelectedIndex?  Currently SelectedItem is the observer of SelectedIndex.

Comment: Is this a homework question? It is ok if it is but you need to tag it appropriately.

Comment: There is no information about it in web,if i could find anything i will not ask question here.But all is ok,you can delete this

Comment: @ChrisPorter,can you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131818/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-mvvm-light-toolkit (answer's last comment) i dont want to reask again,but i have no time

Comment: I can see the comment and it looks like adcool2007 has answered it for you with an edit to his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Based on the limited info in your question, I think you would need to set up two-way bindings from your listbox's SelectedItem property to a property in your ViewModel.

If you need more info, please provide some more code and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correct the answer is: Yes.
If you set SelectedIndex in your code then SelectedItem will change accordingly.

If I have not understood your question, please explain further.

Answer (score 1):

**SelectedIndex** reflects the index of the item being selected and **SelectedItem** reflects the selected item itself. So a changes to one of them will change the other one as well.